# How to put a hyperlink in a label, during coding mode?

Tags: c#, text, hyperlink, visual-studio-2012, label

I am creating a BMI calculator, and I am wondering how to let a user click on a hyperlink when a text coded to show in a label. This is what I have so far.:

```
else if (bmi >= 35 && bmi <= 40)
{
     bodytypetextLabel.Text = "Visit this website. http://www.sears.com/fitness-sports-treadmills/c-1020252";
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in front of the "" Hyperlink so that it is made available as a hyperlink in run form for a user to click if he runs into that BMI result. Please help. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: do a google search tons of great examples out there

Comment: Haha, yea, I did. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f26203db-193f-4eb3-a2d4-29e1f5628310/ Found that. Did not help, because the person is putting a URL on different brackets. I want mine to show right after bodytypetextLabel.Text is shown, if it's possible. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4):

#### Try this code:

```
bodytypetextLabel.Text = "Visit this website <a href=\"http://www.sears.com/fitness-sports-treadmills/c-1020252\">here</a>";
```

Comment: What class is this? Does not work for me with a System.Windows.Forms.Label.

Comment: @duesterdust that's the wrong control for starters.  You need to use a linklabel.

Answer (score 1):

### **it's very easy :**

**1.  you need to add :**

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
```

**2. it's that :**

```
    private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a link label instead of regular label to enable the hyperlink functionality.

You can visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an "a" tag, an "a" tag without a URL is just like a label. Hope this helps someone.