# how to update datatable hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable and it contains a website url and I am displaying entire data in gridview, I want to add hyperlink to all existing urls before binding to gridview.

I am getting data dynamically from database , So I use autogenenerate= true

is it possible ?

Comment: Check if there is a way to make a column type in a data grid view a hyperlink, there should be a way to do this , check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044170/how-to-put-a-hyperlink-in-a-label-during-coding-mode)

Comment: Please update your question and provide the code piece that you talk about.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [OnRowDataBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2) event and from there trying to infer which cells contain a URL and then, turn them into a link:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                cell.Text = $"<a href='{cell.Text}'>{cell.Text}</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```